# Draytek SSL VPN connection incorrect subnet mask and gateway

Tags: ssl, vpn, draytek

I have remote machine connecting to our office lan through a draytek 2930 router in our office with a fixed IP (FW3.3.0). I have set it up to use SSL VPN with Draytek smartvpn client software on the remote machine connecting with a username and password. The smartvpn connects successfully to the router giving a green vpn light and status connected on the client. The router shows the connection as well. ipconfig /all on the remote machine is below.

The question is why can I not ping any other work machine other than the router 192.168.10.1? ultimately I want connect to intranets and via samba to local shares but lets start with ping. I suspect it is to do with the subnet mask and default gateway being incorrect on the drayssltunnel adapter but I don't know where to set them. The IP address comes from the routers inbuilt DHCP server but I can't see where to specify the subnet mask or gateway for vpn connections.

Thanks,
Adrian

---

```
>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : george
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

PPP adapter DraySSLTunnel:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : DraySSLTunnel
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.102(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-FC-38-2E-7E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A0-B3-CC-E0-0F-09
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e826:4ba1:372f:3c53%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.75(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 245412812
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-E0-C7-A9-A0-B3-CC-E0-0F-09

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::9e97:26ff:fe22:5ef2%11
                                       192.168.1.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{7CB34103-4A28-490C-B49E-97A61AA607A0}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:10fb:1320:3f57:f599(Pref
erred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::10fb:1320:3f57:f599%13(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{FC382E7E-EA41-4983-8BD7-A75FD0081F41}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C7E8EB1B-A1CC-4442-8806-9D444AEDFB5F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Reading further I think the subnet mask and default gateway are fine when connecting point to point via VPN. I now think the issue might be a configuration issue at the router with allowing traffic onto the LAN. From the remote machine I can ping the internal router ip 192.168.10.1 fine and I can also see the web interface of the router via the ip address in a web browser. But it won't let any other traffic out of the router onto the local lan.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that the Subnet mask and gateway are fine. The solution is to add the internal ip address range to the firewall rules. It seems the VPN tunnel gets an internal IP address but then still has to go through the router firewall to get to the network.